# How do I add fields to views contextual filters

Tags: views

I have created a view definition based on a custom table I have.  I have happily been creating simple views.

I would like to create a view with a contextual filter, but wwhen I click on it the only field being listed is my main ID field.  I would like to filter on another field.  How can I add a field to be added to the contextual filters selection?